# What kind of tests should I write?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

**BACKGROUND**

I'm writing a little game using Java, slick2d and other frameworks. Slick2d does not make it easy to write unit tests, but that's something I can't get around. One of the goals of the project was to have some test coverage but...

**THE PROBLEM**

Well... I wrote a 200-line test case, with 15 tests, and all for a class with only a single method.

I tested everything I could think of: invalid arguments, combinations of invalid arguments, swapping method calls and so on. I know I can't test everything, and I know I don't need to test code from libraries (Java API, slick2d API, logback API, etc.), but even in that case, I can get pretty crazy with tests, and I believe that I won't be able to finish it if I write 15 tests for every method I create. So...

**THE QUESTION**

Where does good TDD draw the line at writing tests? Exactly what should I test, and what can I safely ignore?

OBS: For those of you wondering, the single-method class for which I wrote 15 tests was loading some strings into an array, and its method would retrieve the string, given the line and file as argument.

OBS2: I'm not skeptical of unit testing at all. I actually want to incorporate them in my project (whenever my API allows me) from the ground up. I just want to finish the project too, and don't die writing tests all day long.

Comment: You write tests for 3 reasons:  1) Because the boss/certification process/whatever says so.  2) To find existing bugs.  3) To facilitate "regression testing" after you make changes.  The type of tests you do will depend on the purpose of them.  (But keep in mind what you want to test.  It does no good to run a dozen different strings through an algorithm if it's not sensitive to what's in the string, but you might want to test minimum-length/maximum-length strings, et al.  Test boundary conditions, stress conditions (large data sets), etc.  Test handling of invalid inputs, especially.

Comment: If you have a more specific question on Test Driven Development then please take a look at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following **book**: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321146530/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) 
from Amazon
Beside the book recommendation, When you design your tests, you have a lot of work at the beginning, but at a point, for every new code, **most of your test logic will already be on place**.
I would also suggest to make sure you are focused on **intrusion prevention** as well (code that test for SQL injection, buffer ovf and so)
Another point to remember is that when the one who wrote the code is the one who wrote the tests, you might want **someone else** that will try to break it down... not for everything, but at least for part of it.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly write unit tests only for public methods. I would stop writing test for a method when I think it is working the right way and only add more tests for the method if I find a bug.

Comment: I think it's a good way to do it. Adding more tests into the critical part of the application is always better.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about TDD remember the approach is test first just because tests will drive your design and how the final API would look like. If you use that approach, the line will be a bit clearer on where to stop writing new tests.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in proper TDD you'd actually first write the test of the new functionality you'd like to add. Initially it would fail, until you have fully implemented what you were after, along with the assertions that verify that the behavior is indeed correct.

Therefore, you just continue the process of adding more tests as you find yourself needing new features. That way, the tests drive the code you write, and not the other way around.